# Cloud Functions bucket.upload() is not running at all

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

here is what I am trying to do using Firebase:

1. create a backup file from realtime database
2. upload to firebase storage
3. do this every morning

but I am having problem on number 2; after the log of back up file creation success, no other log appears, not even a failed message.

[no log after file creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Ac8.png)

Even worse is that it sometimes works, which makes me doubtful about the consistency of the functionality.

my code:

```
    var promiseFileCreation = function(fileName, jsonBackup){
        console.log("promiseFileCreation starting");
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
            fs.writeFile('/tmp/'+fileName, jsonBackup, function(fs_err){
                if(!fs_err){
                    resolve("File "+fileName+" creation success");
                } else {
                    reject("File "+fileName+" creation failure: "+fs_err);
                }
            })
        }).catch(function(error){
            reject("FileCreation Error");
        })
    }

    var promiseBucketUpload = function(fileName, fileDest){
        console.log("promiseBucketUpload starting")
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
            console.log("promiseBucketUpload promise starting")
            bucket.upload('/tmp/'+fileName, { destination: fileDest }, function(upload_err){
                if(!upload_err){
                    resolve("File "+fileName+" upload to "+fileDest+" success");
                } else {
                    reject("File "+fileName+" upload to "+fileDest+" failure: "+upload_err);
                }
            })
        }).catch(function(error){
            reject("BucketUpload Error: "+error);
        })
    }

    Promise.all([promiseText, promiseDate, promiseTitle, promiseLikedCount, promiseViewCount, promiseComments]).then(function (values){

        var jsonPostObj = {
            post: [],
            counter: []
        }

        jsonPostObj.post.push({
            date: values[1],
            text: values[0],
            title: values[2]
        })

        jsonPostObj.counter.push({
            likedCount: values[3],
            viewCount: values[4]
        })

        var jsonCommentsObj = JSON.parse(values[5]);

        const jsonArchiveObj = {...jsonPostObj, ...jsonCommentsObj}

        var jsonArchive = JSON.stringify(jsonArchiveObj);

        const yesterday = getYesterdayDateFull();
        var fileName = "archive_"+yesterday;
        var fileDest = "history/"+yesterday.substring(0,4)+"/"+yesterday.substring(4,6)+"/"+fileName;

        console.log("Archive file name: "+fileName);
        console.log("Archive destination: "+fileDest);

        promiseFileCreation(fileName, jsonArchive).then(function(resultSuccessFs){
            console.log(resultSuccessFs);

            // BUCKETUPLOAD here
            promiseBucketUpload(fileName, fileDest).then(function(resultSuccessBucket){
                console.log(resultSuccessBucket);

                return promiseBackupResult(true);
            }, function(resultFailureBucket){
                console.log(resultFailureBucket);

                return promiseBucketResult(false);
            })
        }, function(resultFailureFs){
            console.log(resultFailureFs);

            return promiseBackupResult(false);
        });
    }).catch(function(errPromiseAll){
        console.log("Promise.all error: "+errPromiseAll);

        return promiseBackupResult(false);
    })
}
```

I removed unnecessary codes, like other promises. The file creation seems to work fine.

Does anyone see why bucket.upload() is not called at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does this take to run?  Cloud functions are [subject to a timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) (Default is 60 seconds) and it can't be made longer than 9 minutes.  Its probably not the best approach to use them to back up a reasonably large database.  Likewise, since you are writing to /tmp/ you will be limited by the amount of memory your function is running in -- even at best you won't be able to ever backup more than 2GB.

Comment: In a very general sense, what you're doing here doesn't seem like it's using promises consistently.  (It's also a bit hard to read.)  If there is any bit of async work that isn't represented by a promise that's returned from the function, it's not likely to complete.

Comment: @robsiemb According to the log, it takes approx 15 seconds to the point where the logging stops; right before the call of bucket.upload() method. The data I am trying to back up isn't that huge, it's only 2KB when converted into JSON format file.

Comment: Hey, i've been looking into the code you provided and I think that the issue is within the upload_err if, I cannot really understand why it seems to sometimes work and sometimes doesn't as you mention, can you attempt to reformat and check if that conditional is the one causing the issue? Hope it helps.